# Know if a method of a Class ends

Tags: java, android, class

I have a Class, that get me a String of a Data Base.
I call the Class in my Activity, and then I use that string.
The stirng is returned because I get it by Log.d, but the String variable of my Activity don´t get it because the program continues without wait the Class ends.
(SORRY MY BAD ENGLISH)

Code:
Activity:

```
Cargar_Imagen ci = new Cargar_Imagen();
String s = ci.Cargar_Imagen(params...);
```

Class:

```
    public class Cargar_Imagen {
        private Map<String, String> params;
        String sBitmap = "";
        public String Cargar_Imagen(final String email, final String id, final String f1, final Context context, final String type, final View v){
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://feticher.webcindario.com/cargar_imagen.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String s) {
                            Log.d("Imagen", "Se cargo la foto");
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonRespose = new JSONObject(s);
                                sBitmap =jsonRespose.getString("imagen");
                                Log.d("Imagen", "STRING: " + sBitmap);

                                Download_Image download_image = new Download_Image();
                                download_image.Download_Image(f1, type,context, v, sBitmap);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d("Imagen", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d("Imagen", "No se pudo cargar la foto");
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                    Log.d("Imagen", "Ejecutando MAP Cargar Imagen");
                    Log.d("Imagen", "DATOS: " + id + " " + email + " " + f1);
                    Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                    params.put("id", id);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("foto", f1);
                    Log.d("Imagen", "PASO POR AKI");
                    return params;
                }};

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            queue.add(stringRequest);
            return sBitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the concepts of concurrency and use of call-back methods (observer pattern) are being used here since the sBitmap String will not be assigned by the time that the `Cargar_Imagen(...)` method ends since it is assigned in a different thread within a call-back method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sBitmap is assigned after the method gets executed since it's asynchronous. One approach is to declare an interface with a method [for example onFinish(String) ] and pass it as a parameter of Cargar_Imagen, after that you can call it inside your `onResponse.Listener` method.

```
// The interface
interface CallBack {
    public void onFinish(String response);
}

// The activity (which calls Cargar_Imagen) should implement CallBack
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CallBack

    public void onFinish(String response) {
        // here the method did finish, do something with the string
    }

    // somewhere you call to Cargar_Imagen
    String s = ci.Cargar_Imagen(params..., this);
}

// the method signature should receive a CallBack
public String Cargar_Imagen(final String email, final String id, final String f1, final Context context, final String type, final View v, final CallBack callback){
    /* code .... */

    // ...
    // in your onResponse
    callback.onFinish(sBitmap);
```

Comment: In Activity what I must to do?

Comment: if you're calling `Cargar_Imagen` from the activity, implement the interface in the activity, and pass `this` to the new parameter. That should do the job. I updated my answer with an example

Comment: It said: "non-static method onFinish cannot be referenced from static context :/
If make it static make a problem of lenguaje level1.7 : "static interface method calls are not supported at language level 1.7"

Comment: are you sure you're calling it like `callback.onFinish` and not `CallBack.onFinish`?

Comment: Sorry i dont see final CallBack callback :/

Comment: Its WORK! THANKS!

Comment: One thing, onFinish need @Override. 
But the Android Studio tells you haha!
thank you very much!
Greetings from Argentina!

Answer (score 0):

You have written `retrun sBitmap;`, try with the correct `return` and let us know if it solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry I wrtite bad here, i use return, The app run in movil fine but dont do that I want.